# Wood identification

Tags: wood-identification

I've been working with some wood that I was given, but I don't know what type of wood it is. It's a light coloured wood similar to pine, but it has a greenish tint in parts of it. It's got small black streaks inside the wood that look like they might be small knots.

While it would be great to identify the wood in question it would be better if I could go through a process to identify it myself. Is it really just a case of being told what different woods are and learning slowly over time or is there a way I can narrow it down myself? I've tried looking on www.wood-database.com but there are just so many woods on there and they all start to look the same to me after a while.

Is there a good list, maybe, of the ten most common types of wood that I'm likely to see (for England)? If I could learn that, I'm sure I'd be able to identify most of the wood I'm likely to see.

Comment: Does it smell like pine at all?

Comment: You can always post a picture of the wood.  If we can identify it we would be able to tell you how as well.

Comment: This is two different questions and should be asked as such. If you want to identify the wood you're working with, a picture would be a great help.

As far as a process ... it comes with time and seeing the woods :)

Comment: Wood Identification questions are usually only picture based and hard to answer with certainty. Consider looking at www.wood-database.com. See [Meta discussion](http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/53/are-identification-questions-allowed/60#60)

Comment: This question as it is currently phrased is off-topic because you're asking for help in identifying a specific piece of wood. However, you could possibly make it on-topic by asking for general techniques and resources that are useful in identifying a piece of wood, and removing any reference to the specific piece of wood you're trying to identify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine what type of wood a board/plank is made from?](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/115/how-do-i-determine-what-type-of-wood-a-board-plank-is-made-from)

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure without a picture, but sounds a bit like poplar

Answer (score 0):

Looking on a wood type database would be the best way to do it yourself but it can be a tedious process. If you post a picture someone can help you identify the wood in question. Conversely you can give a really good description and maybe we can help point you in the right direction. For example pine has certain characteristics and you may use one of those in the description and we can help you out that way.

Comment: This would be better as a comment.